# How do I assign values in a list of data frames based on the values from a single data frame?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I am trying to automate some data transformation that I generally have to do by hand, and can’t find a way to conditionally use the values from one data frame to assign values to a list of data frames. I will likely need help making the question more clear, since it is a complicated problem.

**Edit:**
I have a list of dataframes and a single dataframe.

I am trying to use the START and STOP values from the second data frame, to fill in the heading column of the list of data frames, such that when the coords value for each data frame in the list falls between the START and STOP values of the second df, for the file name row that matches the df name in the list, the heading column would contain the value from the Behavior column of the second df.

list of data frames:

```
x <- structure(list(coords = floor(runif(10, min=1, max=40000)), theta = structure(c(13.8547966870419, 
14.8993688012215, 15.410646113828, 15.6703175237307, 14.5498945559588, 
14.8328448615362, 11.9767208496214, 13.4072260529856, 13.9396600622978, 
15.0786802028324), .Dim = c(10L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    NULL)), heading = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10"), class = "data.frame")
y <- structure(list(coords = floor(runif(10, min=1, max=40000)), theta = structure(c(81.0558787122676, 
80.2691170551245, 79.7678190293645, 79.9335529048482, 80.8203989004178, 
80.5388456375162, 80.6148099805207, 80.9577690561259, 81.9290502290329, 
81.955111593859), .Dim = c(10L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL)), 
    heading = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
list1 <- list(x,y)
names(list1)<-c("K8121319_feed3_01","K8121319_feed3_02")
```

single data frame:

```
structure(list(X = 1:20, File = c("K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", 
"K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", 
"K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", 
"K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", 
"K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_03", "K8121319_feed3_03", 
"K8121319_feed3_03", "K8121319_feed3_03", "K8121319_feed3_03", 
"K8121319_feed3_03", "K8121319_feed3_03", "K8121319_feed3_03"
), Behavior = c("Approach", "OutofFrame", "Approach", "Avoid", 
"Explore", "Approach", "Avoid", "Approach", "Avoid", "Approach", 
"OutofFrame", "Approach", "Avoid", "Explore", "Approach", "Avoid", 
"Approach", "Avoid", "Approach", "Avoid"), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L), START = c(0, 23554.2374, 26476.1594, 27898.7844, 30744.0344, 
0, 1788.0749, 3989.3999, 17529.5553, 21696.3191, 26503.1743, 
27836.4285, 0, 4472.4934, 27347.0455, 41267.0268, 42172.5351, 
42471.8554, 43926.1675, 44301.1415), STOP = c(23554.1775, 25517.5797, 
27898.7245, 30743.9745, 44719.9623, 1788.015, 3989.34, 17529.4954, 
21696.2592, 26503.1144, 27836.3686, 44297.3079, 4472.4335, 27346.9856, 
41266.9669, 42172.4752, 42471.7955, 43926.1076, 44301.0816, 45116.0211
), duration = c(393.225, 32.777, 23.749, 47.499, 233.321, 29.85, 
36.749, 226.045, 69.561, 80.247, 22.257, 274.806, 74.665, 381.878, 
232.386, 15.116, 4.99599999999998, 24.2779999999999, 6.2589999999999, 
13.6039999999999)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Original Question/Data**

Basically, I have a list of data frames that all have this general structure: (dput results for one df at bottom)

```
$K8121319_feed3_01
   coords      x.h      y.h likelihood.h     x.MB     y.MB likelihood.MB
1       0 504.3287 877.9026    0.9947414 490.1283 901.2057     0.9918574
2       1 505.9821 878.5404    0.9952422 491.2240 901.8298     0.9882244
3       2 505.7802 878.6948    0.9960060 490.9815 901.6725     0.9895840
4       3 506.5887 878.4921    0.9932485 491.3726 901.6714     0.9887711
5       4 505.5834 878.0211    0.9945126 490.8402 901.3011     0.9904280
6       5 505.3733 878.2440    0.9956381 490.7085 901.2917     0.9911127
        x.t      y.t likelihood.t      x.p      y.p likelihood.p      x.a
1  450.5128 957.8469    0.9986305 507.6661 862.6042    0.3731771 549.7861
2  451.6438 957.8253    0.9989508 507.8567 862.8673    0.4277135 550.9062
3  451.6186 958.0657    0.9989144 508.0289 862.9623    0.4955292 550.1566
4  451.9846 958.0376    0.9989387 508.5574 862.9042    0.5333622 550.7906
5  451.4842 957.7491    0.9987649 507.8273 862.8090    0.4536394 550.8159
6  451.3544 957.9151    0.9988230 507.0331 862.9991    0.4806216 550.0393
        y.a likelihood.a      x.m      y.m likelihood.m    theta heading
1  712.0231    0.9649664 618.3212 623.8601    0.3472545 13.85480      NA
2  712.1076    0.9549243 619.7942 624.1536    0.3459687 14.89937      NA
3  712.5276    0.9648149 619.7963 626.1128    0.3519055 15.41065      NA
4  714.5052    0.9606929 620.4413 626.5804    0.4425002 15.67032      NA
5  714.4543    0.9589433 620.6282 627.1456    0.4323518 14.54989      NA
6  714.6501    0.9615864 620.0085 626.9384    0.6067145 14.83284      NA
$K8121319_feed3_02
   coords      x.h      y.h likelihood.h     x.MB     y.MB likelihood.MB
1       0 492.6928 995.6010    0.9988985 500.8221 1028.505     0.9978373
2       1 492.8400 995.0040    0.9989992 500.4374 1027.900     0.9981084
3       2 492.8416 994.4175    0.9989386 500.2200 1027.537     0.9981918
4       3 492.5573 993.6464    0.9986783 499.7028 1026.006     0.9981108
5       4 492.6018 992.7993    0.9984750 499.7470 1023.899     0.9974792
6       5 492.2953 991.8393    0.9983433 499.9571 1024.894     0.9976745
        x.t      y.t likelihood.t      x.p      y.p likelihood.p      x.a
1  530.8685 1086.848    0.6761467 487.3187 976.1661   0.14095598 798.7275
2  531.3508 1086.615    0.7511309 487.6399 976.0349   0.15382832 800.8520
3  531.5408 1087.401    0.6604453 487.2163 974.9952   0.14430821 798.5768
4  530.6860 1088.123    0.6541176 487.8687 974.0737   0.15584856 798.5966
5  531.6422 1087.531    0.7950381 485.7681 972.9353   0.12393418 798.4612
6  532.8403 1087.082    0.8325000 485.4099 972.3963   0.10781968 798.8164
       y.a likelihood.a      x.m      y.m likelihood.m    theta heading
1  903.1436    0.9818143 797.3312 890.6576   0.01648542 81.05588      NA
2  902.0165    0.9836377 797.5673 890.6330   0.01425856 80.26912      NA
3  902.1720    0.9853629 797.3771 890.5745   0.01512018 79.76782      NA
4  902.0870    0.9846913 797.4385 890.6240   0.01913673 79.93355      NA
5  902.4894    0.9841179 797.4756 890.8004   0.01662260 80.82040      NA
6  901.0328    0.9826811 797.1801 890.6665   0.01670897 80.53885      NA
```

And so on…
And I have a single data frame that has the name of each data frame in the list along with time values for the beginning and end of different behavioral states (dput at bottom of post):

```
              File   Behavior id    START      STOP duration
1 K8121319_feed3_01   Approach  1     0.00 23554.178  393.225
2 K8121319_feed3_01 OutofFrame  2 23554.24 25517.580   32.777
3 K8121319_feed3_01   Approach  3 26476.16 27898.725   23.749
4 K8121319_feed3_01      Avoid  4 27898.78 30743.975   47.499
5 K8121319_feed3_01    Explore  5 30744.03 44719.962  233.321
6 K8121319_feed3_02   Approach  1     0.00  1788.015   29.850
```

I am trying to use the START and STOP values from the second data frame, to fill in the heading column of the list of data frames, such that when the coords value for each data frame in the list falls between the START and STOP values of the second df, for the file name row that matches the df name in the list, the heading column would contain the value from the Behavior column of the second df.

Start and Stop times for states:

```
structure(list(File = c("K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", 
"K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", 
"K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", 
"K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", 
"K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_03", "K8121319_feed3_03", 
"K8121319_feed3_03", "K8121319_feed3_03", "K8121319_feed3_03", 
"K8121319_feed3_03", "K8121319_feed3_03", "K8121319_feed3_03"
), Behavior = c("Approach", "OutofFrame", "Approach", "Avoid", 
"Explore", "Approach", "Avoid", "Approach", "Avoid", "Approach", 
"OutofFrame", "Approach", "Avoid", "Explore", "Approach", "Avoid", 
"Approach", "Avoid", "Approach", "Avoid"), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L), START = c(0, 23554.2374, 26476.1594, 27898.7844, 30744.0344, 
0, 1788.0749, 3989.3999, 17529.5553, 21696.3191, 26503.1743, 
27836.4285, 0, 4472.4934, 27347.0455, 41267.0268, 42172.5351, 
42471.8554, 43926.1675, 44301.1415), STOP = c(23554.1775, 25517.5797, 
27898.7245, 30743.9745, 44719.9623, 1788.015, 3989.34, 17529.4954, 
21696.2592, 26503.1144, 27836.3686, 44297.3079, 4472.4335, 27346.9856, 
41266.9669, 42172.4752, 42471.7955, 43926.1076, 44301.0816, 45116.0211
), duration = c(393.225, 32.777, 23.749, 47.499, 233.321, 29.85, 
36.749, 226.045, 69.561, 80.247, 22.257, 274.806, 74.665, 381.878, 
232.386, 15.116, 4.99599999999998, 24.2779999999999, 6.2589999999999, 
13.6039999999999)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach should work - we are looking through all the names as well as the list itself to do our lookups. The only thing to note is that using `findInterval()` only searches on the `STARTS`. Based on the data, it appears that this will be sufficient but if there are any coordinates greater than the largest `STOP`, they would not be caught here as an error.

```r
Map(function(flight, lookup) {
    tmp = lookup_DF[lookup_DF[["File"]] == lookup, c("Behavior", "START")]
    flight$heading = tmp[["Behavior"]][findInterval(flight$coords, tmp[["START"]] )]
    return(flight)
    }
    , list1
    , names(list1)
    )

##$K8121319_feed3_01
##   coords    theta    heading
##1   21230 13.85480   Approach
##2   34808 14.89937    Explore
##3   23511 15.41065   Approach
##4   38816 15.67032    Explore
##5    7274 14.54989   Approach
##6   26394 14.83284 OutofFrame
##7   18163 11.97672   Approach
##8    2769 13.40723   Approach
##9   38585 13.93966    Explore
##10  23763 15.07868 OutofFrame

##$K8121319_feed3_02
##   coords    theta    heading
##1    8582 81.05588   Approach
##2   27638 80.26912 OutofFrame
##3    6714 79.76782   Approach
##4   20496 79.93355      Avoid
##5   12542 80.82040   Approach
##6   24201 80.53885   Approach
##7   23939 80.61481   Approach
##8   26953 80.95777 OutofFrame
##9   16873 81.92905   Approach
##10  13671 81.95511   Approach
```

Comment: I have edited with a simpler example df and list. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: ty. I am getting an error again. I'm working on figuring out why but in case you know: (with last traceback) ``` Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, heading, value=c("Approach", "Approach",  : replacement has 40001 rows, data has 10 
6. stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
    "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA)```

Comment: It means this ```tmp[["Behavior"]][findInterval(flight$coords, tmp[["START"]] )]``` evalulates to 40001 rows while the data.frame in that list only has 10 rows. Not sure what is actually happening though to cause it.

Comment: In this code, lookup_DF = the data frame with starts and stops?

Comment: Yes. Lookup_DF includes starts and stops

Comment: I am still getting a row mismatch for some reason ```Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "heading", value = c("Approach", "Approach",  :replacement has 28351 rows, data has 29304```

Comment: That would suggest that there may be either some NAs or there are coords outside of the range of STARTS, specifically on the left side of starts (e.g., there is a -1 but the minimus starts is 1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217677/discussion-between-k8otter-and-cole).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. `List` contains all your dataframes and `StartStop` contains the limits:

```
#First create and id inside all df of your list
myvar<-as.list(rep("Id",length(List)))
myval<-as.list(names(List))
List2<-Map(function(x,y,z) cbind(x,setNames(cbind(x,z)[(dim(x)[2]+1)],y)),List,myvar,myval)
#Function
merge.all <- function(x)
{
  y <- merge(x,StartStop[,c(1,2,4,5)],by.x='Id',by.y='File',all.x=T)
  y$heading <- ifelse(y$coords>=y$START & y$coords<=y$STOP,y$Behavior,y$heading)
  y <- y[!duplicated(y$coords),]
  return(y)
}
#Apply
List3 <- lapply(List2,merge.all)
```

After that you get this:

```
List3[[1]][,c(1,2,20:25)]

                  Id coords likelihood.m    theta  heading Behavior START     STOP
1  K8121319_feed3_01      0    0.3472545 13.85480 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
6  K8121319_feed3_01      1    0.3459687 14.89937 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
11 K8121319_feed3_01      2    0.3519055 15.41065 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
16 K8121319_feed3_01      3    0.4425002 15.67032 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
21 K8121319_feed3_01      4    0.4323518 14.54989 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
26 K8121319_feed3_01      5    0.6067145 14.83284 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
31 K8121319_feed3_01      6    0.7125185 11.97672 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
36 K8121319_feed3_01      7    0.7412189 13.40723 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
41 K8121319_feed3_01      8    0.8015461 13.93966 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
46 K8121319_feed3_01      9    0.7684560 15.07868 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
51 K8121319_feed3_01     10    0.8027051 14.65594 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
56 K8121319_feed3_01     11    0.7045382 15.11358 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
61 K8121319_feed3_01     12    0.7498648 14.24839 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
66 K8121319_feed3_01     13    0.7297653 16.62184 Approach Approach     0 23554.18
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: For me, this solution failed to specifically assign the start/stop times according to the coords value, it just copied down.

Comment: @K8Otter Many sorry! Maybe I did not understand your entire question.

Comment: I am editing the question with a MRE now to make it easier to help me.

Comment: I think this works - your example had no coords that went to other header types

Comment: I edited the smaller data frames to have multiple heading types